# MATLAB expression column indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have an expression that gives a matrix and I want to access an element, without creating a temporary variable, something like this `cov(M)(1,1)`. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a function like this in my path:

```
getRegion = @(matrix, rows, cols) matrix(rows,cols);
```

So that I can then call:

```
getRegion(cov(M), 1, 1);
```

It would also work if you wanted a larger region:

```
getRegion(cov(M), 1:2, 2);
```

Answer (score 6):

It's possible using anonymous functions:

```
>> f11 = @(M) M(1,1);
>> M = [1 2; 9 4];
>> cov(M)

ans =

    32     8
     8     2

>> f11(cov(M))

ans =

    32
```

Or for the purists, here it is with no intermediate variables at all:

```
>> feval(@(M) M(1,1), cov(M))

ans =

    32
```

Comment: Nice solution, but in your feval statement consider changing the parameter to a different name than 'M' for clarity.